# Making Hermitian matrices almost commute

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, oa.operator-algebras

Consider two Hermitian matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. I'm interested in finding another Hermitian matrix $A'$ that is close to $A$ and almost commutes with $B$. More precisely, I'd like to have bounds on the errors $||A-A'||$ and $||[A',B]||$ that can be achieved (where $||.||$ is the trace norm for instance).

I know this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2474) where, if $B$ can also be replaced with a close matrix $B'$, then a bound is given on $||A-A'||$ and $||B-B'||$ under the condition that $[A',B'] = 0$. In my case, the matrix $B$ cannot be modified and I don't require $[A',B] = 0$ exactly.

Comment: You can't make $[A',B]$ small if $[A,B]$ isn't small to start with since the commutator is continuous in $A$.

Comment: The distance $||A-A'||$ can depend on $[A,B]$ (as is the case in the work I cited).

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the Frobenius norm, the problem
$$
\min_{A'} \alpha \|A'-A\|_F^2 + \beta\|A'B-BA'\|_F^2
$$
(for any $\alpha,\beta>0$) is a linear least-squares problem on the $n^2$ real parameters that identify $A'$. In particular,  a closed form for the error can be given in terms of vectorizations, Kronecker products and the like, and it can be solved computationally with various algorithms: QR decomposition, SVD, normal equations, LSQR...

If you formulate it in terms of $\Delta = A' - A$ and chose without loss of generality $\beta=1$, then you get a problem in the form $\min_v \|Mv-b\|^2 + \alpha \|v\|^2$ for which more theory exists (Tikhonov regularization / ridge regression).